# Connected and disconnected sets

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

If A and B are connected, then does it imply that their union is connected?
For example, if $A=[0,2], B=[4,5]$. Is the union connected? I believe the intersection is not necessarily connected, but how about this example? Do I need to have a joint point to conclude that the union is also connected?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Your example shows that the union of two connected set need not be connect.  What is true is that if $A\cap B\ne\emptyset$, then $A\cup B$ is connected.

Answer (score 0):

No, the union of two connected sets is not necessarily connected.  Your example of A= [0, 2], B= [4, 5] should make that clear.  It **is** true that if A and B are connected and their intersection is non-empty then their union is non-empty.